# Can't connect to SFTP server through Sublime 3 Package SFTP

Tags: package, sublimetext3, sftp

I have an SFTP server that I want to connect to with the SFTP package in Sublime Text 3.

For some reason, I get a timeout everytime I try to connect to it. The SSH key is correctly set up, I can connect to the server with WinSCP, FileZilla and PuTTy as well.

Here is the error:

```
Connecting to SFTP server "pirpi.pil.dk" as "devafdoede" ....... failure (Connection timeout)
```

It's just the Sublime SFTP package that doesn't want to connect. Here is my config:

```
{
// The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
// Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": false,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "pirpi.pil.dk",
"user": "devafdoede",
//"password": "password",
//"port": "22",

"remote_path": "/mypath",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
//"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
//"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a specific `ssh_key_file` if you're on windows.

From the SFTP FAQ:

> For Windows, Sublime SFTP uses PSFTP, which is released alongside
>   PuTTY. **Any key loaded into Pageant** will automatically be used. It is
>   also possible to supply a .ppk private key file as the ssh_key_file
>   setting for an SFTP remote. .ppk files can be generated from scratch,
>   or an existing OpenSSH private key, via PuTTYgen. All of these
>   utilities can be downloaded from the PuTTY site, however none are
>   required for Sublime SFTP to fully function.

You need to create your private key file with PuTTYgen and open Pageant and select the key.

Read more here:
http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/faq#SSHKeys
http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.61/htmldoc/Chapter9.html#pageant

You need to specify the ssh_key in your sftp config

Comment: should be declared twice, on your `server` config and on `sftp-config` file

Comment: I had both versions: id_rsa and id_rsa.ppk.  I was instantly getting (Connection timeout) with the non-ppk version.  So I switched to the .ppk version in Sublime's SFTP config and now it works.  Then I switched back to the non-ppk version and it works with that one now too!?...  My private key is password protected.  It only asked for my password when I switched to the .ppk version.  When I switched back to non-ppk it didn't ask for my password.  This is weird.

Comment: Maybe you needed to accept the RSA fingerprint on first connect? Use the one without password query.

Comment: All I did was switch using my .pem key to a .ppk key and it worked. Thanks!